# React Native - Request Location in android 7, 7.1 dont work, return timeout

Tags: android, react-native, geolocation, location, android-7.0-nougat

I have worked in Project relate to Location.

```
static currentLocation(myLocationCallback) {
  try {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (location) => {
        if (this.validLocation(location.coords)) {
          this.locationToAddress(location.coords, myLocationCallback);
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        /**
         * error.code === 2 GPS is turn off
         */
        myLocationCallback({ code: error.code, message: error.message });
      }, 
      { timeout: 15000, enableHighAccuracy: false }
    );
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('request location catch error', e);
  }
}
```

I known that we need focus in `{ timeout: 15000, enableHighAccuracy: false }`

I have tried:

Case 1: NO OPTION (remove `{ timeout: 15000, enableHighAccuracy: false }`) from function.

Case 2: `{ timeout: 15000, enableHighAccuracy: false }`

Case 3: `{ timeout: 15000, enableHighAccuracy: true }`

Others: maximumAge, distanceFilter.....

All of them don't work in Android 7, Android 7.1 too. But Android 6, Android 8 work as well. iOS work fine.

Please help, I am stucking at this issue.